# subtracting two years with to_char and to_number

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to subtract two dates. First I convert the date field to years using to_char, then convert to a number using to_number. However I get an error in the query when subtracting two years:

```
to_char((order date),'yyyy')
to_char((beginning of the year),'yyyy')
```

I tried converting to a number using

```
to_number(to_char((order date),'yyyy'),'9999')
to_number(to_char((beginning of the year),'yyyy'),'9999')
```

Comment: try this select to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy'))-10 as diff  from dual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `extract`; it is simpler than what you're doing:

```
select extract(year from order_date) - extract(year from trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy')) as result
from some_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `EXTRACT` function:

```sql
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date)
```

Or, if you want to get the actual difference and measure full years (accounting for months and not just years), then you can use `MONTHS_BETWEEN` and divide by 12 and round down:

```sql
FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), order_date) / 12)
```